# Format axis and label for line graph using ggplot2

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, line, visualization

Here is my sample data:

```
Singer <- c("A","B","C","A","B","C")
Rank <- c(1,2,3,3,2,1)
Episode <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
Votes <- c(0.3,0.28,0.11,0.14,0.29,0.38)

data <- data_frame(Episode,Singer,Rank,Votes)
data$Episode <- as.character(data$Episode)
```

I would like to make a line graph to show the performance of each singer.

I tried to use ggplot2 like below:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=Episode,y=Votes,group = Singer)) + geom_line()
```

I have two questions:

1. How can I format the y-axis as percentage?
2. How can I label each dot in this line graph as the values of "Rank", which allows me to show rank and votes in the same graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

To label each point use:

```
geom_label(aes(label = Rank))
# or
geom_text(aes(label = Rank), nudge_y = .01, nudge_x = 0)
```

---

To format the axis labels use:

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
# or without package(scales):  
scale_y_continuous(breaks = (seq(0, .4, .2)), labels = sprintf("%1.f%%", 100 * seq(0, .4, .2)), limits = c(0,.4))
```

---

Complete code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(Episode), y = Votes, group = Singer)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_label(aes(label = Rank)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
```

[image]

---

Data:

```
Singer <- c("A","B","C","A","B","C")
Rank <- c(1,2,3,3,2,1)
Episode <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
Votes <- c(0.3,0.28,0.11,0.14,0.29,0.38)

data <- data_frame(Episode,Singer,Rank,Votes)
# no need to transform to character bc we use factor(Episode) in aes(x=..)
```